# Limited string takes unlimited characters in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, input

[Code + Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG098.png)

I tried testing a normal string input and output before proceeding to higher levels including creating a datatype for taking large values of numbers. What I find out here is as you can see even though the string is limited in taking 5 characters, it takes as much as I can feed it and shows the full too. I don't know what the problem is, if it is some kind of compiler error. I thought restarting might solve the problem so I restarted the IDE as well as the PC but no luck. I asked my friends about it and showed the code, the same happened for them too. I could find no answers on the internet about it. I use Atom IDE updated to the latest version. Hope someone could help me...I need it real quick cause I need that custom datatype for my Semester Assignment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char i[5];
  scanf("%s", &i);
  printf("%s", i);
}
```

Comment: It's still a buffer overflow and it's still undefined behavior. You can't really expect anything with undefined behavior.

Comment: You can run a red light 100 times before you get hit by a truck. You won't find any answers explaining why it didn't already happen.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 but isn't there any other way to limit the input

Comment: Never use `%s` without restricting the input such as with `scanf("%4s", i);`

Comment: @FireDrop6000 you can change your `scanf` format specifier to `"%4s"`, 4 being the maximum characters that array can hold. You could also use `fgets` for a whole line of input, and you can limit the length with that too.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 yes did it and it worked

Comment: In short: C doesn't have any kind of bounds-checking. It's the responsibility of you as the programmer to make sure you don't go out of bounds.